# Change tab bar badge size in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

How to change the tab bar badge size?

I set the tab bar badge value with position

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[4].badgeValue = "1"
```

but I can't change the red circle tab bar badge size.

Thank you!

Comment: Use custom tabbar

Comment: Unless you want to create your own custom tab bar then you don't.  The only way to do this will be to go rooting around in the view hierarchy or doing something like adding your own custom view.  Both of these could get your app rejected.  In general it's not a good idea to fight the standard controls.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's working

```
func addRedDotAtTabBarItemIndex(index: Int) {
    for subview in tabBarController!.tabBar.subviews {

        if let subview = subview as? UIView {

            if subview.tag == 1234 {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
                break
            }
        }
    }

    let RedDotRadius: CGFloat = 5
    let RedDotDiameter = RedDotRadius * 2

    let TopMargin:CGFloat = 5

    let TabBarItemCount = CGFloat(self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items!.count)

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let HalfItemWidth = (screenSize.width) / (TabBarItemCount * 2)

    let  xOffset = HalfItemWidth * CGFloat(index * 2 + 1)

    let imageHalfWidth: CGFloat = (self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![index] as! UITabBarItem).selectedImage!.size.width / 2

    let redDot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset + imageHalfWidth - 7, y: TopMargin, width: RedDotDiameter, height: RedDotDiameter))

    redDot.tag = 1234
    redDot.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    redDot.layer.cornerRadius = RedDotRadius

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.addSubview(redDot)

}
```